# Is there a TabHost that allow swiping and works with views?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have built my application a couple of years ago, and I made it without any `Fragments`. Therefore all the initializations of the UI are placed in one main class (the main `activity`)
I am not interested to change the whole coding of my application so I can use a `ViewPagerIndicator` or `ActionBarSherlock`. Therefore I am asking if is there any `TabHost` which handles horizontal swiping gestures that is not hard to set up, and using `Views`, like the orginal `TabHost`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the great [ViewPagerExtentions](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions) library, which allows swiping, and working as I wanted.